# Why do fully connected NNs exist?

Tags: neural-network

I have implemented my own little NN with the back-propagation algorithm. What I do not understand at the moment is, if your hidden layer is fully connected with the input layer and fully connected with the output layer, aren't the weights for the nodes in the hidden layer updated equally for each hidden node?

Comment: No, they are not.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro But only if you choose random weights at the beginning, right? I just tried out here, setting all weights to zero initially (unfortunately not included in the link parameters):

http://playground.tensorflow.org/#activation=tanh&batchSize=10&dataset=circle&regDataset=reg-plane&learningRate=0.03&regularizationRate=0&noise=0&networkShape=4&seed=0.86133&showTestData=false&discretize=false&percTrainData=50&x=true&y=true&xTimesY=false&xSquared=false&ySquared=false&cosX=false&sinX=false&cosY=false&sinY=false&collectStats=false&problem=classification&initZero=false&hideText=false

Comment: Yes, you have to use random weights, if you set them all to the same value then there is no way to "break the symmetry".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the back propagation algorithm :

[Back Propagation Algorithm Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation)

You can see weights update formula contains current weights values and also the outputs of nodes, then weight update differ for each connection between nodes.

And **NEVER** set the weights to 0. Either to any value. Always set them random.

Also Note this type of questions should be better asked on [Data Science Stack Exchange site](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) or [Cross Validated Stack Exchange site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)